# How to create a keypair for resource only once at deployment without regeneration and redeploy on each cdk deploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I have a task to generate cloudfront keypair dynamically in code for url signing, but they are changed on each cdk deploy:

1. First I create a stack cloudfrontKeyStateStack which generates SSM parameter:

   ```
    const exist = new StringParameter(this, 
                                       'Parameter', {allowedPattern: '.*',
                                       description: 'Parameter to check if the stack was created',
                                       parameterName: "/prod/enabled",
                                       stringValue: 'false',
                                     });
    this.cfExist = new cdk.CfnOutput(this, 'CfKeyExist', { value: exist.stringValue, exportName: 'CfKeyExist' });
   ```
2. cloudfrontKeyStateStack should be created before cloudfrontKeyStack, because I am using the output
3. In the cloudfrontKeyStack I am creating generating new key pair only if the output from CfKeyExist is false. Then I am updating the SSM parameter to true like this:

   ```
    new StringParameter(this, 'Parameter', {
    allowedPattern: '.*',
    description: 'Parameter to check if the stack was created',
    parameterName: `/${props.getEnvironmentType()}/enabled`,
    stringValue: 'true',});
   ```
4. The reason for this parameter is to generate the keypair dynamically  only once and not the update it each time I use cdk deploy, but the if statement is not working. Maybe because of the declarative nature of Cloudformation

**Is it possible to generate the keypair dynamically only once during the deployment of the Cloudfront stack without updating it on next cdk deploy? If yes how can I achieve it?**